# Raspberry Pi Magic Mirror/Google Assistant

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, troubleshooting, software-compatibility, google-nest

I installed a magic mirror software and installed google assistant with it but then after I started the module and tried giving a command everything but then the display shut off. The Pi still has power but will not project any outward display.

Comment: You need to add more info, logs, what have you done to trouble shoot?

Comment: maybe you have a  bad display ... also, do you have a question?